AADSTS500208 error for Multitenant .NET app with Entra External ID
Summary
In a multi-tenant app in .NET 8, using Entra External ID and Workforce tenant users from the workforce tenant and users from the external with administrative roles can log in successfully. Regular users without roles fail with AADSTS500208. How can we configure our app to allow external users to log in without assigning them administrative roles?

We operate a SaaS service where multiple applications come together to provide solutions for our customers (B2B). Our customers use a unified portal to log in and manage their systems.
Previously, we used a single tenant (our workforce tenant) to manage both internal and external (customer) users. However, with the introduction of Entra External ID, we decided to separate internal and external users into two tenants. Our goal was to keep our application multi-tenant while improving user management.
The Problem
We have been working with this setup since Entra External ID was in preview and have encountered several challenges. One persistent issue has no clear answers online. Here's the setup and the problem we're facing:
Application Setup
Our application is a .NET 8 app with a multi-tenant configuration.

The application registration resides in our Workforce tenant.
A service principal is configured in our External tenant.
The appsettings.json and Program.cs configuration is as follows:

appsettings.json
{  
  "WorkforceTenant": {  
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",  
    "Domain": "workforceDomain",  
    "TenantId": "workforceTenantId",  
    "ClientId": "workforceAppRegistrationClientId",  
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"  
  },  
  "MultiTenant": {  
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",  
    "Domain": "common",  
    "TenantId": "common",  
    "ClientId": "workforceAppRegistrationClientId",  
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"  
  }  
}

Program.cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfidentialClientApplication>(sp => ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder  
    .Create(builder.Configuration["WorkforceTenant:ClientId"])  
    .WithClientSecret(builder.Configuration["WorkforceTenant:ClientSecret"])  
    .WithAuthority(new Uri($"{builder.Configuration["WorkforceTenant:Instance"]}/{builder.Configuration["WorkforceTenant:TenantId"]}"))  
    .Build());  

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)  
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>  
    {  
        builder.Configuration.Bind("MultiTenant", options);  
        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers = new[]  
        {  
            "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{workforceTenantId}/v2.0",  
            "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{externalTenantId}/v2.0"  
        };  
    })  
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()  
    .AddDistributedTokenCaches();  


What Works

Users from the Workforce tenant can log in successfully.
Users from the External tenant with administrative roles assigned (e.g., Global
Administrator, Guest Inviter) can also log in.

What Doesn't Work
For users in the External tenant without any administrative roles (e.g., regular B2B users), logging in fails with the following error:

AADSTS500208: The domain is not a valid login domain for the account type.

User types

All users in the External tenant are of type Member with creation type Local account.
The issue persists whether users are added manually via Entra Admin Center or programmatically using the Graph API.

Questions

How can we configure our multi-tenant application to support B2B customers in the External tenant without assigning them administrative roles?


Which option did you choose to create the application?

The app registration in Entra ID is created with "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant)"

Yes so you are getting this error you should select the 3rd option which supports multitenant and personal accounts too

We get the same error. Note that it is not personal accounts we try to login with but accounts from the External ID tenant.

Try https://<TENANT_ID>.ciamlogin.com/<TENANT_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize for authorize endpoint

See my comment on rbrayb answer. I have tried using the ciamlogin.com authorization endpoint with error AADSTS500206.

For your external users, have you tried:
https://[ciam tenant].ciamlogin.com/

instead of:
https://login.microsoftonline.com


Thanks for your answer! The current configuration is for both workforce and exetrnal tenants. I have tried switching to ciamlogin.com and then I instead get this error for all users trying to login: AADSTS500206: The account type can't be used for the application you're trying to log into.
